# OpenVPN, Does Perfect Forward Secrecy Key Need To Be Kept Private?

Tags: openvpn

On my OpenVPN server I generate a `pfs.key` file (perfect forward secrecy) using the command `openvpn --genkey --secret pfs.key`, in my client configuration file it includes this `pfs.key` file (and in server configuration file), so my question is, is it 'safe' to give clients the generated `pfs.key` file? I.e. Would giving clients the `pfs.key` file be of any concern in terms of security?

The client config includes the pfs.key file like so

```
tls-auth /path/to/pfs.key
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the keys in the wrong way if the key you generate with `easyrsa gen-dh` is being used in the `tls-auth` line.

The file you generate with `easyrsa gen-dh` only needs to be added to the server configuration via the `dh dh.pem` configuration line.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42415/openvpn-dhparam

> The parameters are just primes, not keys. They don't need to be unique or secret, but they must also not be specially crafted by an attacker.

The key you use for the tls-auth should have been generated using a command like `openvpn --genkey --secret ta.key`

https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Hardening#Useof--tls-auth

Your key used for the `tls-auth` should be kept as secret as possible.  The clients that connect must know it, but you don't want to hand it out to people that shouldn't have access.  This is a shared secret.  It isn't actually required for OpenVPN to be secure, it just adds an additional layer of authentication.

Comment: Sorry I put the wrong command in my question that I'm using for `tls-auth` (fixed), I'm using `openvpn --genkey --secret pfs.key` to generate the `pfs.key` file that I will be handing out to clients that are authorized to connect to the VPN server. But thanks, you've answered my question!